# Where is NumLock in /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/

Tags: keyboard-layout

I want to modify NumLock functionality by editing a file in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/`. But where is it defined so that I can modify its definition?

I hope the new definition works in all keyboard layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not defined on the us keyboard I use, but you can define it like this:

```
key <NMLK>  { [ Num_Lock,   KP_End, KP_1,   KP_Divide   ] };
```

If no key has Num_Lock as its unmodified symbol, it seems you won't be able to set the NumLock modifier, even programmatically with something like `numlockx`.